# A question 2019 Putnam A6

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g$ be a real-valued function that is continuous on
the closed interval $[0,1]$ and twice differentiable on the
open interval $(0,1)$. Suppose that for some real number
$r > 1$,

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{g(x)}{x^r} = 0
\end{equation}

Prove that either
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} g'(x) = 0, \quad \limsup_{x\rightarrow 0^+} x^r|g''(x)| = \infty
\end{equation}

I'm wondering why we can't always conclude that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} g'(x) = 0$. Using Lhopital's rule, we get
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{g(x)}{x^r} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{g'(x)}{rx^{r-1}}
\end{equation}

Since $r>1$, for this limit to be finite, we must have $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} g'(x) = 0$. I would like to know where my reasoning falls apart.

Comment: L'hospital's rule only applies if the two individual limits exist,  so IF the limit of $g'$ exists,  then it must be 0.   But it doesn't cover the case where that limit doesn't exist

Comment: Why can we use L'Hopital anyways? $g(x)$ need not go to $0$; remember that L'Hopital's rule applies for indeterminant forms $0/0$ or $\pm \infty/\infty$.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer If $g(x)$ doesn't go to $0$ then the given condition $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{g(x)}{x^r} = 0$ doesn't hold.

Comment: Thank you @Alan!

Comment: @Math_Day No problem, converted it to an answer since that did it.  Note I am not spending any time trying to figure out the rest of the problem, how to show that limit not existing forces the limsup condition on $g''$

Comment: So you're not looking for an answer to the question itself? That is something I'd have loved to look at a little more in detail, although I can understand if it's not the focus of your post.

Comment: I looked up the official exam out of curiosity and this question is incorrectly stated. The second condition should be $\limsup_{x \to 0^+} x^r|g''(x)| = \infty$. The questions are found at this link: https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/Putnam/2019/2019PutnamProblems.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L'hospital's rule only applies if the two individual limits exist, so IF the limit of g′ exists, then it must be 0. But it doesn't cover the case where that limit doesn't exist.

(Converted from comment).   You'd then have to show that if the limit doesn't exist, that'd make the second limsup condition hold.